# (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "std_logic" & "std_logic_vector"

Tags: digital-logic, simulation, vhdl, questasim

I am relatively new to VHDL, and I am getting the errors below although I used the same procedure before:

```
vcom -work work -2002 -explicit -vopt -stats=none 
Questa Intel Starter FPGA Edition-64 vcom 2021.2 Compiler 2021.04 Apr 14 2021
-- Loading package STANDARD
-- Loading package TEXTIO
-- Loading package std_logic_1164
-- Loading package NUMERIC_STD
-- Loading package MATH_REAL
-- Loading package std_logic_arith
-- Loading package STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED
-- Compiling entity testbench_pack
-- Compiling package testbench_package
** Error: (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "std_logic".
** Error: (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "std_logic".
** Error: (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "std_logic_vector".
** Error: (vcom-1136) Unknown identifier "std_logic_vector".
** Note: VHDL Compiler exiting
```

The code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity testbench_pack is
end testbench_pack;

package testbench_package is
    procedure assert_floor_and_door(
        constant clock      : in std_logic;
        constant reset      : in std_logic;
        variable floor      : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        variable door       : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
    );
    
end package testbench_package;

package body testbench_package is
    procedure assert_floor_and_door(
        constant clock      : in std_logic;
        constant reset      : in std_logic;
        variable floor      : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        variable door       : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0)
    ) is
        variable door_s_int  : natural;
        variable floor_int   : natural;
    begin
        -- Procedure code here...

        -- Convert door to integer
        door_s_int := to_integer(unsigned(door));

        -- Convert floor to integer
        floor_int := to_integer(unsigned(floor));

        -- Assertion for floor value
        assert floor_int >= 0 and floor_int <= 7
            report "Assertion failed for floor value: " & integer'image(floor_int)
            severity failure;

        -- Assertion for door value
        assert door_s_int >= 0 and door_s_int <= 3
            report "Assertion failed for door value: " & integer'image(door_s_int)
            severity failure;
    end procedure;
end package body testbench_package;

architecture Behavioral of testbench_pack is
    signal s_clock    : std_logic := '0';
    signal s_reset    : std_logic := '0';
    signal s_floor    : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := "000";
    signal s_door     : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := "00";

begin
    process
    begin
        wait for 5 ns;
        s_reset <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        s_reset <= '0';
        wait;
    end process;

    process
    begin
        wait for 2 ns;
        s_clock <= not s_clock;
        wait for 2 ns;
    end process;

    process
    begin
        wait for 20 ns;
        s_floor <= "001";
        s_door <= "01";
        wait for 10 ns;
        s_floor <= "010";
        s_door <= "10";
        wait for 10 ns;
        s_floor <= "111";
        s_door <= "11";
        wait;
    end process;

    process
    begin
        wait for 5 ns;
        testbench_package.assert_floor_and_door(s_clock, s_reset, s_floor, s_door);
        wait;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overcome these errors by moving the `package` code into its own file and compiling both files in your compile command.

This [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/Zx4C) link demonstrates your code compiling without errors.

You also need to `use` your `testbench_package` package in the `testbench_pack` file:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.math_real.all;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use ieee.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

use work.testbench_package.all;

entity testbench_pack is
end testbench_pack;
```

Answer (score 4):

The scope of `library` and `use` extends only until the end of the current design unit, which is the `entity` declaration. If you add an `architecture` for the same `entity`, you can also use the imported names there, because these are visible through the `entity`.

The `package` is its own design unit though, and needs its own set of `library` and `use` clauses. Typically, that is done at the beginning of a separate file.